# override FE0.network by conf no working

Tags: networking, systemd-networkd

systemd version 241

## cat /etc/systemd/network/FE0.network

```
[Match]
Name=FE0

[Network]
Address=192.168.2.180/24
Gateway=192.168.2.1
```

## cat /etc/systemd/network/FE0.network.d/xx.conf

```
[Network]
Address=192.168.1.110/24
```

when i `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`，the FE0 interface address is 192.168.2.180, not 192.168.1.110, why?
and when i `ifconfig FE0 192.168.1.123`, then `ifconfig` ,the FE0 interface address is 192.168.1.110(from xx.conf), why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`man 5 systemd.network` says on the `Address=` keyword:

> **Address=**
>
> A static IPv4 or IPv6 address and its prefix length, separated by a "/" character. **Specify this key more than once to configure several addresses.** The format of the address must be as described in inet_pton(3). This is a short-hand for an [Address] section only containing an Address key (see below). **This option may be specified more than once.**

If you use the currently-recommended `ip addr show` instead of the deprecated `ifconfig` tool, you should see that your FE0 interface now has two addresses: `192.168.2.180/24` and `192.168.1.110/24`. The `ifconfig` tool can only show the first of them.

If you want your `/etc/systemd/network/FE0.network.d/xx.conf` file to *override* the existing address rather than *adding a second one*, you'll need this syntax:

```
[Network]
Address=
Address=192.168.1.110/24
```

The `Address=` line with no address indicates you wish to discard any addresses mentioned in other configuration files, and only use the address(es) in the override file.

All the systemd settings that have the qualifier *"may be specified more than once"* work the same way: if you want to change the setting in an override file instead of adding to the setting specified in the main configuration file, you must explicitly set it to blank first.

Comment: thx，you are right! but I used Address=，then resart systemd-networkd, ip address show dev FE0, there are still two ip address